# Connect Four In Idiomatic Scala

Tags: scala

### Learning Scala

I'm trying to learn Scala and I'm interested in criticism about how to make my code more idiomatic. I've programmed a simple Connect-four game. Can I get some feedback?

https://github.com/jamiely/connect-four-scala

The two most important classes are [Board.scala](https://github.com/jamiely/connect-four-scala/blob/master/src/connect_four/Board.scala) and [Game.scala](https://github.com/jamiely/connect-four-scala/blob/master/src/connect_four/Game.scala). They are shown below for your convenience as well.

### Board.scala

```
package connect_four

import connect_four._

class Index(val row: Int, val col: Int) {
    def tuple(): (Int, Int) = (row, col)
}

class Size(val width: Int = 7, val height: Int = 6)

class Board(val size: Size = new Size()) {
    val length = size.width * size.height
    val board = (for (_ <- 0 to length-1) yield Markers.Empty).toArray

    // Return a list of index objects
    def getPositionIndices() = {
      for {
          row <- 0 to size.height-1
          col <- 0 to size.width-1
      }
        yield new Index(row, col)
    }

    def isEmpty = board.forall(x => x == Markers.Empty)

    def isInBounds(index: Index) = {
      val row = index.row
      val col = index.col 
      row >= 0 && row < size.height && col >= 0 && col < size.width 
    }

    def fromIndex(index: Index): Option[Int] = {
      if(isInBounds(index)) {
          Some(index.row * size.width + index.col)
      }
      else None
    }

    def move(marker: Markers.Marker, index: Index): Boolean = {
      val pos: Option[Int] = for {
        pos <- fromIndex(index)
        _ <- Some(updatePosition(marker, pos))
      } yield pos
      !pos.isEmpty
    }

    // Updates the given position without performing a check. 
    // @returns     Returns a pair of the marker that was put at the position and the position.
    def updatePosition(marker: Markers.Marker, position: Int) = {
      board(position) = marker
      (marker, position)
    }

    def markerAt(index: Index): Option[Markers.Marker] = {
      for {
        pos <- fromIndex(index)
        m <- Some(board(pos))
      } yield m
    }

    def posIs(marker: Markers.Marker, index: Index) = {
      val result: Option[Boolean] = for {
        m <- markerAt(index)
        // return the result of a check against the marker
        result <- Some(m == marker)
      } yield result

      result.getOrElse(false)
    }

    def hasMovesLeft = board.exists(x => x == Markers.Empty)

}
```

### Game.scala

```
package connect_four

import connect_four._

class Game {
    val board = new Board
    var currentMarker = Markers.A
    // directions are deltas used to check board locations in the cardinal directions
    val directions = (for {
      i <- -1 to 1 
      j <- -1 to 1
      if !(i==0 && j==0)
      } yield (i, j)).toList

    def checkPosition(index:Index, marker:Markers.Marker, delta: (Int, Int), steps: Int): Boolean = {
        if(steps == 0) {
            true
        }
        else if (board.isInBounds(index) && board.posIs(marker, index)) {
            val newIndex = new Index(index.row + delta._1, index.col + delta._2)
            checkPosition(newIndex, marker, delta, steps-1)
        }
        else {
            false
        }    
    }

    def isWin:Boolean = 
      board.getPositionIndices().exists(testWinAtIndex)


    def testWinAtIndex(index:Index): Boolean = {
      board.markerAt(index) match {
        case None => false
        case Some(Markers.Empty) => false
        case Some(m) => directions.exists(delta => checkPosition(index, m, delta, 4))  
      }
    }

    def getFirstEmptyRowInColumn(c: Int): Option[Int] = {
      def helper(row: Int): Int = {
        if (row < 0) {
          row
        } else {
          val marker = markerAt(new Index(row, c))
          if (marker == Some(Markers.Empty)) row else helper(row - 1)
        }
      }

      if(!board.isInBounds(new Index(0, c))) {
        None
      }
      else {
        val r = helper(board.size.height-1)
        if(r < 0) None else Some(r)
      }
    } 

    def toggleMarker(): Markers.Marker = {
      currentMarker = if(currentMarker == Markers.A) Markers.B else Markers.A
      currentMarker
    }

    def updateBoard(index: Index): Markers.Marker = {
      board.move(currentMarker, index)
      toggleMarker()
    }

    def move(mv: Move): Option[Markers.Marker] = {
      if(isWin) {
        None
      }
      else {
        for {
          row <- getFirstEmptyRowInColumn(mv.col)
          result <- if(row >= 0) Some(updateBoard(new Index(row, mv.col))) else None
        } yield result
      }
    }

    def markerAt(index:Index): Option[Markers.Marker] = board.markerAt(index)

    def getCurrentMarker: Markers.Marker = currentMarker

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice code! You did the most things correct only some hints:

- Use case classes. They bring you some nice methods (like copy or apply) and result in easier maintainable code. There is no need any more to instantiate objects directly with `new` - instead it is possible to use the apply-method (factory pattern). Later, when your application grows, maybe you detect that you have to much object creations - with case classes it is easy to cache object instantiation inside of the apply-method - without changing any call side code.
- If you need mutable state then centralize and encapsulate it in single places. The Game class does have some public `var` - refactor this. No one outside of this class should be able to change the state of this `var`.
- Make Game immutable. You should hold different game instances at the call side such as your UIConsole.
- In Scala algebraic data types are more powerful than enumerations.
- Instead of sharing libraries in your repository use build tools like sbt.
- Move test code outside of your main code - this makes it easier to publish your code as an standalone application.

Syntax clues:

- You can leave curly braces when you have single expressions.
- For-expressions can be nested: `for(a <- ...; b <- ...; c <- ...)`
- Methods with side effects should marked with parentheses: `def x { println } -> def x() { println }`
- Type Application is deprecated, use App instead
- There is no need to move each class to its own file. In particular when you have a lot of small classes (like your Move, Markers) it can be more clear to put them together.

Some months ago I have written the game Othello in Scala - [here](https://gist.github.com/2472666) is the result. Maybe it offers some concepts to you.